# TypeError: education.map is not a function This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-props, destructuring, array.prototype.map

Hi Everyone i am trying to do something that i have a main file of Nextjs name as **Project.js** and I am importing the components init, i am facing the issue in exporting the data from main file to object named as Resume to the component educationsection...

```
import EduSection from "@/components/EduSection";
import ExpSection from "@/components/ExpSection";
import IntrestSection from "@/components/IntrestSection";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import ProjectSection from "@/components/ProjectSection";
import ResumeHead from "@/components/ResumeHead";
import SkillSection from "@/components/SkillSection";
import React from "react";

function projects() {
  let Resume = {
    Head: {
      firstName: "Abdullah",
      lastName: "Naseer",
      email: "mianabdullah125125@gmail.com",
      phone: "03061356081",
      about: "lorem lipsemmmm ",
    },
    exprience: [
      {
        companyName: "AirLift Express",
        role: "Dispatch Coordinator",
        duration: "March 2022, November 2022",
        jobDes: "leremmmmmmmmm",
        address: "Kohinoor, Faisalabad",
      },
      {
        companyName: "Akount",
        role: "Fr developer",
        duration: "Jan 2011 - Feb 2015",
        jobDes: "did This and that",
        address: "San Monica, CA",
      },
    ],

    education: [
      {
        name: "BSSE",
        address: "Faisalabad",
        duration: "2020-2024",
        schoolName: "GCUF",
      },
      {
        name: "BSSE",
        address: "Faisalabad",
        duration: "2020-2024",
        schoolName: "GCUF",
      },
      {
        name: "BSSE",
        address: "Faisalabad",
        duration: "2020-2024",
        schoolName: "GCUF",
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <>
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,700"
          rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
        />
        <div className="container">
          <ResumeHead {...Resume.Head} />
          <div className="details">
            <ExpSection exprience={Resume.exprience} />
            <EduSection education={Resume.education} />
            <ProjectSection />
            <SkillSection />
            <IntrestSection />
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    </>
  );
}

export default projects;
```

The Issue is in the **EduSection** i am importing the subcomponent init name as **EduItem**
`

```
import React from 'react'
import EduItem from './EduItem'

function EduSection(education) {
  return (
    <>
        <div className="section">
        <div className="section__title">Education</div>
        <div className="section__list">
          {education.map((education, index) => (
          <EduItem key={index} {...education} />
        ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default EduSection;
```

```
import React from 'react'

function EduItem(name,address,duration,schoolName) {
  return (
    <>
        <div className="section__list-item">
            <div className="left">
              <div className="name">{name}</div>
              <div className="addr">{address}</div>
              <div className="duration">{duration}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="right">
              <div className="name">{schoolName}</div>
              {/* <div className="desc">did This and that</div> */}
            </div>
          </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default EduItem
```

the same thing i am doing with the exprience section and it is working fine but giving error in Education Section
the error is saying : **Server Error
TypeError: education.map is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.**
I'll be thankful if any buddy help

the expectation was

```
{education.map((education, index) => (
          <EduItem key={index} {...education} />
        ))}
```

will get the props data from the main file to the eduitem and then in edusection
but it is throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call map on object that contains all props. Your property `education` is assigned to a field in this object. Check this out:

```
import React from 'react'
import EduItem from './EduItem'

function EduSection(props) {  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="section">
        <div className="section__title">Education</div>
        <div className="section__list">
          {props.education.map((education, index) => (
            <EduItem key={index} {...education} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default EduSection;
```